# How to ignore one UIView below in while having transparent top UIView - iOS CocoaTouch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

My view hierarch looks something like this

```
View
  DeckContainer
   Card  (back card)
   Card  (this is front card)
```

The card is semi-transparent.

Can I somehow see through "back card" and create kind of X-Ray effect ?

Image will clarify this:

[image: Screenshot showing hierarchy]

I just don't want to see the "Cineworld" card, but I want to this card be there (the front card could be moved)

Comment: Can you not hide the view? `backCardView.hidden = YES;`

Comment: @OliverAtkinson I don't want to see though the first card and see the second card.  But I want this second card to be there. Like X-Ray, "the skin exist" but I want to see behind the "skin" while first card is above the "skin".

Comment: Reduce the opacity ? Is that what you wanted ? a transparent back card ?

Comment: So do you want the back card to be fully transparent when the top card is covering it, but when the top card is moved, you reveal the semi-transparent card behind it?

Comment: @wottle Yes exactly. Parts of the "back card" not covered by the top card should be visible.

Comment: I think that's going to be impossible to do with standard iOS views.  I think you would need to get into CoreGraphics and build your own frames and everything, calculating the overlap and making that part of the back tile(s) fully transparent, while the area of the bottom cards that don't overlap would be partially transparent.  I also think that would be confusing for the user if you really are trying to build a card stack.  I think you would be better off making the top card opaque and the bottom cards semi-transparent.  Then offset the top card so the user can see the cards behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a card background view whose `backgroundColor` has a transparency (`alpha`) set to less than 1 (maybe 0.5) when it is the top card. Something like:

```
View
    Card (back card outer view)
        Card Background view
        Card Icon view
        Card Label view
    Card (front card outer view)
        Card Background view
        Card Icon view
        Card label view
```

You'll then be able to see the back card through the front card.

The card outer view allows moving the card as a whole by just change the `frame` of the outer view.

The Card outer view `backgroundColor` should be clear (e.g., `[UIColor clearColor]`).

Result will look something like this (the front and back "cards" are offset to make it easier to see content of both cards):

[image]

Comment: You probably haven't read the bottom part of my question (below the image) "I just don't want to see the "Cineworld" card, but I want to this card be there (the front card could be moved)"  I basically want the "X-ray" effect, so the green background would be visible through "Piccadilly Circus" card but NOT Cineworld. But the Cineworld would be there, so when you place two cards shifted little bit (like in your example) part of the "Cineworld" would be visible.